# Lego Racers in Special Box

Tags: racers

I am trying to collect all of the Lego Racers sets in the unique box design that set 8121, 8120, 8119, and 8122 have. Does anyone know if those are the only four in that box design? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set 8121, 8120, 8119, and 8122 are the only ones with a red box.

[image]

It also comes in black
[image]

See this link for a complete list of boxes

[Catalog : Original Boxes: Racers: Tiny Turbos](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=O&catString=179.571)